# Cannot `convert` an object of type BitArray{1} to an object of type Int64. Julia

Tags: type-conversion, julia

I am very new in Julia, so maybe it is stupid question. I have the following code:

```
a = [1.0, 2.0];
b = [2.2, 3.1];
Int(a.>b)
```

It gives me an error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type BitArray{1} to an object of type Int64
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Int64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.

Stacktrace:
 [1] Int64(::BitArray{1}) at ./sysimg.jl:77
 [2] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
```

The command `1(a.>b)` works well.
Could You explain me:
**Why my implicit conversion did not work?**

Comment: I don't see a question in the "Update" part.

Comment: Sorry, It was a mistake. Everything works. I just realise that `rand(1)` and `rand()` gives different types. Hard, after MatLab... But much more logic and strict! Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.>b` is of type `BitArray{1}`. With `Int(a.>b)` you are trying to convert an array, namely a `BitArray`, to a single integer, which doesn't make sense.

Instead you probably want to convert the elements of the array to integers:

```
julia> a = [1.0, 2.0];    

julia> b = [2.2, 3.1];    

julia> Int.(a.>b)         
2-element Array{Int64,1}: 
 0                        
 0
```

Note the dot in `Int.(a.>b)` which [broadcasts](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) the conversion to every element.

The reason why `1(a.>b)` works is because it is being translated to `1*(a.>b)`. This is a multiplication of a number and an array which is an element-wise operation.

Comment: Thank You fro an answer, so I have this:`a = [1.0];
b = [2.2];
c = Array{Int}(5);
c[2]=Int.(a.>b)[1]`, it works good, but i am not sure it is a julia way...

Comment: This looks awkward. What are you trying to do?